# Is it possible to get video frame by frame using video_player in flutter?

Tags: flutter, frame, frames, flutter-plugin, flutter-video-player

I am working on one of the flutter applications where I want to fetch a video frame by frame using the video_player plugin. Is this possible to do so? or is there any other way for the same.

Comment: I'd suggest you read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post. Do you have some code? A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue that we can help you with?